# Difference in Amazon S3 storage types; Standard, Reduced Redundancy and Glacier? What is cloud front?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Thinking about starting a image upload service on my website with PHP where users can upload their photos. Have found Amazon S3 http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ and I think it is a good solution for storing pictures. But Iam  be confused about the different storage types

Standard Storage
Reduced Redundancy Storage
Glacier Storage

Have tried to read on the site but does not become wiser. Is it how often I want to access the data? Glacier just seems to be for backup if you don't want to access the data very often and Reduced Redundancy is the same as standard but without the secure connection? Can someone briefly explain the difference between them and what fit best for me (a website/service where users can upload photos).

Have also read that people recommend using CloudFront with Amazon S3 http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/. What is it good for? Can anyone explain why? It's the same here, have tried to read on Amazon but

> give developers and businesses an easy way to distribute content to
>   end users with low latency, high data transfer speeds, and no minimum
>   usage commitments.

even if it sounds good does it not tell much what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/05/19/announcing-amazon-s3-reduced-redundancy-storage/

> Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) is a new storage option within Amazon
>   S3 that enables customers to reduce their costs by storing
>   non-critical, reproducible data at lower levels of redundancy than
>   Amazon S3’s standard storage. It provides a cost-effective, highly
>   available solution for distributing or sharing content that is durably
>   stored elsewhere

Glacier: http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/

> Amazon Glacier is a secure, durable, and extremely low-cost storage
>   service for data archiving and online backup

Cloudfront is a CDN: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

> Amazon CloudFront is a content delivery web service. It integrates
>   with other Amazon Web Services products to give developers and
>   businesses an easy way to distribute content to end users with low
>   latency, high data transfer speeds, and no minimum usage commitments.

Think of it as a geographically dispersed web cache where it keeps copies of your images from s3, so they can be served up to customers based on the closest location to the nearest Cloudfront distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Guessing that Reduced Redundancy Storage fits best for me?

But to be honest I do not really understand Cloudfront and CDN. I have also read the benefits of cloudfront. But why? What do CloudFront do to create these  benefits like high data transfer speeds, etc. What is the different  between using Amazon S3 without CloudFront and Amazon S3 with CloudFront? To clarify my question. What do CloudFront do to make eg. higher data transfer speed?

Comment: this is simply a network related question, essentially, if the content is served from within the same region as you, there are less hops to (less routes) to get the data from them to you, which makes it faster to serve content to you or your end users. In every request you make there could be as many as 30 hops, directed through switches, routers, firewalls, perhaps slower networks based on older technology without faster capabilities

Answer (score 0):

[image: Differneces between various storage classes]

Difference :  between various storage classes
Cloudfront: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/